# How to modify a mapping involving the special key name <Plug>?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I use [this plugin](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) (incsearch.vim) which changes the search function in vim by highlighting the text dynamically while typing the regex after `/` or `?`.

For the plugin to work I had to add these lines in my `~/.vimrc` :

```
map /  <Plug>(incsearch-forward)
map ?  <Plug>(incsearch-backward)
```

I suppose the result is that whenever I hit `/` or `?`, some functions (`incsearch-forward()` and `insearch-backward()`) provided by the plugin are called to take care of the search.

I would like to modify those mappings, so that the plugin's functions are still called but the search begins automatically with `\v`, the *very magic* mode is enabled and I don't have to escape `(`, `)`, `{`, `+` etc.

Without calling the plugin's functions it would give something like this :

```
map /  /\v
map ?  ?\v
```

But I don't know how to call the plugin at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to modify those mappings, so that the plugin's functions
>   are still called but the search begins automatically with \v, the very
>   magic mode is enabled and I don't have to escape (, ), {, + etc.

You can achieve that by using your previous mappings, by changing some plugin options. This approach avoids cluttering the search line with the `\v`. From the [documentation](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim/blob/master/doc/incsearch.txt#L161):

```
By default 'magic' option, all you can set is 'magic' or 'nomagic',
and in addition, default option has porability problem. see: 'magic'
In contrast to default 'magic' option, |g:incsearch#magic| enable
you to set 'very magic' |\v| and 'very nomagic' |\V| in adition to
'magic' |\m| and 'nomagic' |\M|.
This option doesn't cause porability problems, so you need not worry
about this problem. No other pattern related programs are affected by
this option.
Usage: >
let g:incsearch#magic = '\v' " very magic
let g:incsearch#magic = '\V' " very nomagic
let g:incsearch#magic = '\m' " magic
let g:incsearch#magic = '\M' " nomagic
<
default: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found. I tried the other way around the first time, sorry.

```
map /  <Plug>(incsearch-forward)\v
map ?  <Plug>(incsearch-backward)\v
```